# Is it possible to open a browser Window with desired content type using JS?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I had some data in an `HTML` table which wanted to be downloadable as a spreadsheet.
Since both excel and open office can read `CSV`. I am generating a `CSV` using a `PHP` script on the server by passing it the data from HTML table using `JS`.

I was wondering If I could directly open a browser window with that `CSV` as its conetnt and if could set its content type to `CSV`, Will this work ? Is there a way to modify content type on the client ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: anyways, can you help me out ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have JS solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side, you need to have scripts that can generate two different "views" of the same data, the HTML table for viewing online, and the CSV for exporting.  Once you have that, it's just a matter of using window.open in javascript to open a window on the CSV view.